# dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libecryptfs1'

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt, dpkg, ecryptfs

OS: Linux Mint 20.3

I usually get this error whenever I do sudo apt update.

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libecryptfs1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
```

But it has never caused any issue.

Now that am doing my Linux mint upgrade to 21, the upgrade stopped by throwing the following error.

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libecryptfs1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 409767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libecryptfs1.triggers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Error - Return code: 100
```

When I try to reinstall it the followin error happens

```
encrypted32@anonymous24:~$ sudo apt-get autoclean
[sudo] password for encrypted32:        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

encrypted32@anonymous24:~$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall libecryptfs1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqt5networkauth5 python3-simplejson stunnel4 x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-randr-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libecryptfs1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1492 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libecryptfs1 amd64 111-5ubuntu1 [36.0 kB]
Fetched 36.0 kB in 2s (17.6 kB/s)       
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libecryptfs1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 409767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libecryptfs1.triggers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output for `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libecryptfs1.triggers` below:

```
$���m��mo�L�D��;�%g�?w��ŷ���ovH0��a�5��*�ؒ��l͛�S�iy�r�O7����%L]�
```

Not sure what that output means

Note: i did `apt update` before i began the upgrade
Any help on fixin this is appeciated.

As per @a.b recommendation I ran all the commands

Pasting the output of the last command below

```
encrypted32@anonymous24:~$ sudo apt-get -f reinstall libecryptfs1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libqt5networkauth5 python3-simplejson stunnel4 x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-randr-dev
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libecryptfs1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1492 not upgraded.
Need to get 36.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 kB disk space will be freed.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libecryptfs1 amd64 111-5ubuntu1 [36.0 kB]
Fetched 36.0 kB in 1s (30.9 kB/s)       
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libecryptfs1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 409767 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libecryptfs1 (111-5ubuntu1) over (111-0ubuntu7) ...
Setting up libecryptfs1 (111-5ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
```

Now, how do I resume my upgrade ? From the Mintupgrade tool or is there any command ?

Comment: Add the output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/libecryptfs1.triggers` to the question. Also, did you run `apt update` before `apt upgrade`? Add that to the question as well.

Comment: Again, add that information to the question. Do not post it in the comments. It is also best to use `apt` and not `apt-get`.

Comment: Done, thanks @NasirRiley. Even with just apt got the same error

Comment: This looks like corruption happened in the past and damaged a few package installation metadata.

Comment: @A.B the upgrade process was happening smoothly and during the upgrade process i saw in the terminal that it was replacing **focal** repos with new **Jammy** repos and then installing the new packages it dowloaded until it met with the **missing file error**

What can possibly be done now ?

Comment: I did write "in the past". Since you saw for the first time "dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libecryptfs1' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed"

Comment: @A.B No, i see it every time when i give a `sudo apt update` even before the upgrade. But since all the updates usually happen normally and dont halt, i used to ignore the warning.

Comment: That's what I mean: this should never have been seen. You let a problem go to bigger proportions by not addressing it before doing the dist upgrade.

Comment: A package always have installation files. At the very least `/usr/share/doc/packagename` (even if it's just a symlink).

Comment: @A.B yes my bad, I should have fixed it prior to upgrade.

In the `/usr/share/doc/libecryptfs1` folder i find 2 files- changelog.Debian.gz and copyright. Thats it

Comment: Actually I'm not sure the triggers file (which for most libraries just tell to run ldconfig) is from the former installation of the package or the newer intallation of the package. So I'm not sure corruption happened in the past or is currently happening. So I can't give a method to reinstall the package without risking worsening the problem.

Comment: YOu can just remove the triggers file and try again what you did.

Comment: @A.B First and foremost what is this package libecryptfs1 ? Is it related to encryption ? If so Let me know how i get rid of encryption. 

If this is not an important package, can we remove it ?

Comment: Thirdly what does the below error mean, is it not able to install the .deb file ? if yes, can we install it manually without the terminal ?

`Preparing to unpack .../libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libecryptfs1.triggers'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libecryptfs1_111-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb`

Comment: it means: corruption

Comment: @A.B is there a way to remove encryption without formatting ?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'll assume the system got filesystem corruption in the past. If this is limited to one package's meta-data that's fine. If other corruption remains or is still happening (eg: hardware issue), this might be worse. So important data should be backed up first.

The goal is to reinstall this package, while disregarding its former meta-data parts which makes it uninstallable. The offending file will just be moved out of the way. Normally this trigger file just triggers running `ldconfig`: that's what has to be done after installing a library package providing shared object libraries. As I don't trust either the .deb file currently in `/var/cache/apt/archives` just empty the whole cache first so it gets redownloaded and revalidated. The triggers file should be replaced with a fresh version from the upgrade.

First verify there is no filesystem full or nearly full (`df -h`) and make room if needed.

All following commands must be run as root (use `sudo` if needed).

```
mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libecryptfs1.triggers /root/libecryptfs1.triggers.badfile

apt clean
apt update

apt-get -f reinstall libecryptfs1
```

Then the package can be removed as usual. If encryption depends on it, it should not be removed.

Comment: I ran all the commands you mentioned and have pasted the output in the question post. How do di resume the mint upgrade now from where it left?

Comment: Your initial question didn't ask how to proceed: it was added later. Please avoid changing the goal of the question at each step you reach. Anyway, apparently there are no half installed packages, you can just proceed by doing as before: `apt upgrade` followed by `apt full-upgrade`. If the first command complains about half installed packages, add a -f option. Don't add it if it doesn't complain.

Comment: @ab Thanks for the help . In the first comment Nasir Riley asked to add everything in the question rather than in the comment and hence I did. Am new to stack exchange and am learning how things work here unlike forums.

Now when I give apt upgrade it says it needs to download more 1.2 GB of files. But when the ugrade was happening, the download phase was completely over and the error happened only in the upgrade phase.

Now I do not know where this is fetching packages from -jammy or focal. 
If focal, then it would be a complete wreck.

Comment: There's a difference: I addressed your question. You're asking a new question, after I answered the previous question. That's why I choose to just answer in comments for now, and I don't know if I'll change my answer.

Comment: I don't know all your settings. How did you run the upgrade the first time? You just have to do the same. You can add a -d option (download only) and see where the download comes from to get an idea.